# BIP > Sorting is not working on BIP RTF template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

I am trying to sort data in my BIP rtf template but it is not working. The report is being generated fine but the group 'Primary Focus' is not being sorted.

This is how report is being generated:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zratu55hgf9o77/481539039485767out.pdf?dl=0

And this is how 'Primary Focus' needs to be sorted:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7pu2yb86iuccjuv/03.pdf?dl=0

Please find sample [xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdw7kp3x9etrr1z/BIP%20ROH%20SH%20Visit%20Record%20Report%2017%20%281%29.xml?dl=0) and [rtf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4p58xo03xrfnfmq/ROHSHCVDR_A.rtf?dl=0).

Rest everything is fine just 'Primary Focus' group is not being sorted.

Comment: You have shared the same link to your images twice.

Comment: Link is fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the sort code

```
<?sort:ssFocusTypePrimary;'ascending';data-type='text'?>
```

before the grouping code.

```
<?sort:ssFocusTypePrimary;'ascending';data-type='text'?><?for-each-group:current-group()[xdoxslt:format_date(ssReportedDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)>= (xdoxslt:format_date($StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)) and (xdoxslt:format_date(ssReportedDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))<= (xdoxslt:format_date($EndDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)) and starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName,$Clinic) and ssVisitType=$VisitType];./ssFocusTypePrimary?>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[image]